# where do you report stackexchange siterip?

Tags: discussion

I was searching for an answer to my question and found this site that is directly using text from this site with no reference:

https://www.queryxchange.com/q/13_301313/keep-safari-from-hijacking-the-media-buttons-from-controlling-itunes/

the url is even strongly reminiscent of:
[Keep Safari from hijacking the media buttons from controlling iTunes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/301313/keep-safari-from-hijacking-the-media-buttons-from-controlling-itunes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Please [contact us](https://apple.stackexchange.com/contact) directly using the on-site form. Select the "Stack Exchange content is being reproduced without attribution" option from the drop-down

#### [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do)

> When should I report these sites?
>
> - The site is a proxy. […]
> - The site doesn't follow attribution requirements. […]
> - The site uses a different license or claims ownership of the content. […]
>
> When should I not report these sites?
>
> - They follow all the attribution requirements. […]
> - You landed on the [malware page](http://stackexchange.com/about/malware). […]